# Toggle modal component from another sibling component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I need to call `ngOnInit` method of a component from another component. What I'm trying to do is, to open a modal on a click event from another component.

service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CustomerCreateneweventService {

  private subject = new Subject<any>();

     sendMessage(message: boolean) {
      console.log(message);
         this.subject.next(message);
     }

     clearMessage() {
         this.subject.next();
     }

     getMessage(): Observable<any> {
         return this.subject.asObservable();
     }
}
```

modal component

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { CustomerCreateneweventService } from '../../../services/customer/customer-createnewevent.service';

@Component({
              selector: 'app-customer-home-createnewevent',
              template: `
                <app-modal [(visible)]="newEventWindowOpen">
                    <h3 style="text-align: center">Create a new project</h3>      
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="newEventWindowOpen != newEventWindowOpen">Close</button>
                    </div>
                 </app-modal>
              `
            })


            export class CustomerHomeCreateneweventComponent implements OnInit {
              newEventWindowOpen: boolean;
              subscription: Subscription;

               constructor(private createNewService:CreateNewProjectService,private messageService: CustomerCreateneweventService) { 
                 this.subscription = this.messageService.getMessage().subscribe(
                   message => { this.newEventWindowOpen = message; });
               }
            }
```

I want to toggle this modal from another component:

Other component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomerCreateneweventService } from '../../../services/customer/customer-createnewevent.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-customer-home-leftsidebar',
  template:  '<h4 (click)="toggleModal()">Toggle</h4>',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-home-leftsidebar.component.css']
})

export class CustomerHomeLeftsidebarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private messageService: CustomerCreateneweventService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  toggleModal(){
    this.messageService.sendMessage(true);
  }    
}
```

These two components don't have parent-child relationship. I need to implement this approach because there are many other components which should be able to toggle this same modal.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Additionally you probably shouldn't be manually calling the lifecycle methods; factor out what's reused whenever the modal is re-opened into another public method.

Comment: Didn't get that

Comment: @AchiraShamal He means follow this rule: https://github.com/mgechev/codelyzer/issues/427

Comment: @JBNizet, I tried to implement what you said, But still modal is not toggling.

Comment: @jonrsharpe could you please have a look at my code

Comment: It works thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Above code is working. I just had to add component to html code

```
<app-customer-home-createnewevent></app-customer-home-createnewevent>
```